# Symfony2 - send email Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

After configuration smtp in prameters.yml I trying to send email but I have this type of warning:

ContextErrorException: Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in /home/crashend/domains/tombax.com/public_html/gbuy/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/KeyCache/DiskKeyCache.php line 273

On the localhost everything worked fine but the problem appeared after transfer project to the server.
Emails are not deliver.

Code from controller where are send emails:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Hello Email')
            ->setFrom(array('exapmle@abc.net' => 'Tom'))
            ->setTo(array('exapmle2@abc.net' => 'Jan'))
            ->setBody('abcd')
    ;
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Code from parameters.yml:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: smtp.myserver.com
mailer_user: exapmle@abc.net
mailer_password: pass
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comment this:

```
if (is_writable($tmpDir = sys_get_temp_dir())) {    
    $preferences->setTempDir($tmpDir)->setCacheType('disk');
}
```

in the /vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/preferences.php everything works fine.
I think that the problem was in the permission to the directory. Swiftmailer uses sys_get_temp_dir() function which trying refer to /tmp directory.

Comment: well /tmp should be writeable, there will be lots of breakage if it is isn't

Answer (score 1):

[I had the same problem today. Find this article](https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2012-11-05-fedora-private-tmp/)

All I have to do was: set **PrivateTmp** to **false**

```
PrivateTmp=false
```

in

```
/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service
```

and then reload services

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your spool path set wrong (it is different on server, than your dev environment)

Look in your config.yml   and make sure the SwiftMailer spool directory is correct, and that it exists  (and your user has permissions to it) on the server.

Comment: I have set spool on { type: memory }

Comment: Well the error is on a line trying to create a cache key in a directory that doesn't exist. So it seems to not be using mem

Comment: When I replace type: memory on file and set path then emails are saving to the file and when I trying to send those from command line I have the same warning in terminal.